# Webpack error when exporting an Algolia search bar (with autocomplete) react component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storyboard, algolia

I have a component library using React + Storybook, and everything was working fine. Then I created a new component (An Algolia search bar component) which also worked fine (when viewing in Storybook), but when I tried to export (in my index.ts - to be consumed by other libs), I got some errors with dependency:

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '[path]/design-system/dist'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ../design-system/dist/index.es.js 12:0-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '[path]/design-system/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ../design-system/dist/index.es.js 13:0-29
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '[path]/design-system/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ../design-system/dist/index.es.js 15:0-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '[path]/design-system/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

webpack compiled with 3 errors
No issues found.
```

The crypto one I fixed by adding this code to my `design-system` `package.json` file (as per a lot of suggestion here in StackOverflow):

```
"browser": {
  "crypto": false,
},
```

but the `http` and `https`, if I add them to this list above, I get another issue:

```
requester-node-http.esm.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: http__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.Agent is not a constructor
    at ../design-system/dist/index.es.js (requester-node-http.esm.js:9:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
```

Which appears on Google Chrome console (the compile phase runs ok), so the app just loads brank with this JS error.

I'm still facing this issue, and looks like it just happens when I try to use Algolia lib (react hooks), so I wonder which setting I should add to Webpack or TS to ignore these errors as my app runs only on the browser.

Edit 1:
I also tried to add this config below into `main.ts` file from Storybook (extending Webpack config), but also with no success:

```
webpackFinal(config, { configType }) {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      ...config.resolve.fallback,
      "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
    };
    return config;
  }
```